# Accuracy of known constants versus precision

Tags: newtonian-gravity, error-analysis, physical-constants, statistics

I am wondering if the community could comment on the accuracy of the known constants versus their precision.  What I mean is while many values like the electron magnetic moment are known to extraordinary precision ~12 decimal places, what do we know about the accuracy of the reported values?  Especially when one considers that there are empirical constants such as the gravitational constant $G$ for which there is no theory which can relate said constant to others, it seems like there is potential hole(s) in our understanding which might suggest any theory that could relate an empirical constant to other known ones with high precision might require a fundamental re-alignment of those other constants to be consistent.

Comment: What's wrong with having constants that are not independent? Alice could measure the electron magnetic moment while Bob measures the fine structure constant. The fact that they're mathematically related means that only one of them needs to have a record breakingly small error bar to improve out knowledge of both quantities.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to note that some of the constants of nature are "infinitely accurate" by definition because we have defined our system of units so that these constants are exact integers.  The meter is defined to be the distance travelled by light in vacuum in 1/299,792,458 of a second (exactly);  this means that the speed of light is exactly 299,792,458 m/s.  Similarly, the kilogram is defined to be the unit of mass so that Planck's constant is exactly equal to $6.62607015 \times 10^{−34} \text{ kg}\cdot\text{m}^2/\text{s}$.  The fundamental unit of charge and Boltzmann's constant are also exact numbers because of how we have defined the units of charge and temperature in the SI system.

This does leave several other constants of nature that just have to be measured, such as the gravitational constant, the mass of the electron, various neutrino mixing angles, etc.  It is conceivable that a theoretical model could predict that (for example) the gravitational constant $G$ times the electron mass $m_e$ should be some exact integer fraction of the speed of light squared.  If so, then we would need to look at the error bars on the measurements of $G$ and $m_e$ and see if the measured values are consistent with this prediction.  If they are not, then the theoretical model would be wrong and we would have to discard it.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your thoughtful response.  I agree with your point that some constants are defined so technically they're accuracy is absolute.  However, doesn't this shift the burden of definition onto the meaning of the units?  In other words, until there is an agreed upon absolute for a definition of time (or more generally spacetime), then anything defined relative to time shares this underlying ambiguity?

Comment: (sorry still getting used to website with character limits and timing constraints for edits continuing from above)
More specifically, With mass defined relative to h yet only an empirical understanding of G, this seems like a potential hole.  Can you comment more on "we would look at error bars on G and me"?  How are they different from those values reported uncertainty i.e. precision?

Comment: @AdamBrooks: I don't quite understand your question about an "absolute for a definition of time".  Are you talking about an absolute definition for a unit of time?  (We have that;  it's defined in terms of a certain number of oscillations of EM radiation from a particular cesium atom transition.)  Or are you talking about something more philosophical, i.e., "how do we know what time really is"?  That's probably a separate question that might go better on [Philosophy.SE] than here, to be honest.

Comment: As far as the second question, yes, I mean the precision with which those values are known.  Right now there are [26 dimensionless constants of the Universe](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/constants.html) that we think are independent of each other and which need to be measured empirically.  If a theory says "not all of these constants are independent of each other", then we would need to look at the empirical measurements to check this prediction.  If the constants didn't agree with the theoretical prediction within their precision, then the theory would need to be discarded.

Comment: Thank you.  I really appreciate the link you sent!  
In regards to the first question my apologies I suppose my question is leaning towards the philosophical